# remove elements from dictionary with recursive condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given this dictionary:

```py
{
'a': {'maxVal': 2653, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
'b': {'maxVal': 2775, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 678, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 701},
'c': {'maxVal': 3431, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 733, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 755},
'd': {'maxVal': 1907, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 727},
'e': {'maxVal': 2489, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 727},
'f': {'maxVal': 1812, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
'g': {'maxVal': 3888, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783}
}
```

I need to do some "cleaning". I need to iterate through it and compare elemetents where the coords are the same and keep the one with the highest maxVal.

In the given example I would keep `b, c, d,e and g`

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: your dict miss `,` comma

Comment: Why don't you keep `g` instead of `a` ?`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari you are right. I forgot to put the commas in, Ihad to edit the dict for privacy purposes

Comment: @Pantoofle you're right, I edit my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict with the coords as keys, and the key and the dict with the largest `maxVal` seen for these coords as value. Then, you can build your output from it. As no sorting is involved, this will work in O(n).

```
data = {
'a': {'maxVal': 2653, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
'b': {'maxVal': 2775, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 678, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 701},
'c': {'maxVal': 3431, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 733, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 755},
'd': {'maxVal': 1907, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 727},
'e': {'maxVal': 2489, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 727},
'f': {'maxVal': 1812, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
'g': {'maxVal': 3888, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783}
}

by_coords = {}
for key, v in data.items():
    coords = (v['startX'], v['startY'], v['endX'], v['endY'])
    max_val = v['maxVal']
    if by_coords.setdefault(coords, (key, v))[1]['maxVal'] < max_val:
        by_coords[coords] = (key, v)

out = {}
for coords, (key, v) in by_coords.items():
    out[key] = v

print(out.keys())
# dict_keys(['g', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
# They are the ones we expected.

print(out)
#{'g': {'maxVal': 3888, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783}, 
# 'b': {'maxVal': 2775, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 678, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 701},
# 'c': {'maxVal': 3431, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 733, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 755}, 
# 'd': {'maxVal': 1907, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 727}, 
# 'e': {'maxVal': 2489, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 727}}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do something like this:

```
d = {
    'a': {'maxVal': 2653, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
    'b': {'maxVal': 2775, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 678, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 701},
    'c': {'maxVal': 3431, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 733, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 755},
    'd': {'maxVal': 1907, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 727},
    'e': {'maxVal': 2489, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 727},
    'f': {'maxVal': 1812, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
    'g': {'maxVal': 3888, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
}

sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: d[x]['maxVal'], reverse=True)

coordinates = set()
ans_keys = []

for key in sorted_keys:
    my_coordinates = (
        d[key]['startX'],
        d[key]['startY'],
        d[key]['endX'],
        d[key]['endY'],
    )
    if my_coordinates not in coordinates:
        ans_keys.append(key)
        coordinates.add(my_coordinates)

print(ans_keys)
```

Output:

```
['g', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: This gives the expected output, but this is not as efficient as it could be, because the initial sorting is O(n*log(n)), while this can be done in O(n).

Comment: Totally agreed!

Answer (score 1):

```
# your dictionary
x = {'a': {'maxVal': 2653, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
'b': {'maxVal': 2775, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 678, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 701},
'c': {'maxVal': 3431, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 733, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 755},
'd': {'maxVal': 1907, 'startX': 577, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 600, 'endY': 727},
'e': {'maxVal': 2489, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 705, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 727},
'f': {'maxVal': 1812, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783},
'g': {'maxVal': 3888, 'startX': 610, 'startY': 761, 'endX': 632, 'endY': 783}
}

temp = {}
for key  in x.keys():
    # creating cordinate map
    cord = '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(x[key]['startX'],x[key]['endX'],x[key]['startY'],x[key]['endY'])
    if cord not in temp.keys():
        temp[cord] = [key]
    else:
        key1 = temp[cord][0]
        # checking the max value
        if x[key1]['maxVal'] < x[key]['maxVal']:
            temp[cord] = [key]

print(temp.values())
# dict_values([['g'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e']])
```